# how to resolve facebook acces token expiration issue?

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook place serach with graph api. But the access key expires every two hours. For this I have implemented the below code

```
 $app_id = "---";
 $app_secret = "----"; 
 $my_url = "";
$code = $_REQUEST["code"]; 
if (isset($code)) {

    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
      . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
      . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
      . "&code=" . $code . "&display=popup";
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $access_token = $params['access_token'];
}
$FacebookGraphURL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=id,username,name,category,website,likes,location&q='.$keyword.'&type=place&center='.$center.'&distance='.$radius.'&limit=5&access_token='.$access_token;
    $FacebookGraphJSON = file_get_contents($FacebookGraphURL);
```

But this is giving the below error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: code in /opt/lampp/htdocs/APIcomparison/facebook_graph.php on line 24
```

what I am missing ? another thing I don't know what to use  $my_url

Thanks is advance.

Comment: You are trying to access `$_REQUEST["code"]`, whether it exists or not. Check for _that_ with `isset` (and spare the needless copying of th value to another variable).

Comment: @CBroe , I have edited the code to if (isset($_REQUEST["code"]))
but the problem is never get into the if condition, but it should be all the time.

Comment: Why don’t you just use the PHP SDK – tht handles all of this (extracting code, exchanging it for an access token) automatically for you … so no real need to do it “manually”.

Comment: @CBroe actually I'm a novice and don't know how to use php sdk to achieve my goal. Could you please provide any example code or tutorial.

Comment: Download the SDK, it contains an “examples” folder already; and read the docs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you generating the access token via the Graph Explorer tool? If so, those tokens have a 2-hour expiry time.

You can generate an access token with a 60-day expiry time by going through the Facebook Log In / OAuth process, during which you grant your application access to your (or any user's) Facebook user account by clicking the 'allow' button on the authorization dialog. Once you've obtained an access token you can exchange it for a long-lived token.

Details on Facebook OAuth here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

A simple way to generate an access token is to use the Facebook OAuth support provided by Temboo. If you just wanted a single token then you can use the Facebook OAuth wizard, meaning that you won't have to write any code to generate the token. Details here: https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Facebook/

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Comment: @Cormac Driver ,  I visited tembo.com . I have found they said to create a dev fb account and create an app which I already have, but how can I have long lasting access token ?

Comment: If you're using Temboo's InitializeOAuth and FinalizeOAuth Choreos to generate your access token, then check out the optional input on the FinalizeOAuth choreo called "LongLivedToken" - it lets you specify that you want a long-lived access token.